# Pandas replace function does not replace value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to replace values in a column, but for some reason one of the values is not changing. The three values are - `'xxx'` , `'aaa'` and `0`. The problem is with the zero.

This is part of the code I am using:

`df['source'] = np.select(conditions, ['xxx', 'aaa'], default=0)
  df['source'] = df['source'].replace({'xxx': 'xxx', 'aaa': 'aaa', 0: 'test'})`

First I am using `np.select` based on some conditions and since I cant put string value on `default`, I want to replace the zero with another string. And I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Just `df['source'] = df['source'].replace(0, 'test')` or maybe replace `0` with the string `'0'`?

Comment: `since I cant put string value on default` why is that? `default = 'test'` doesnot work?

Comment: @anky It says expected type int,float,complex,none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 may be "0" as a string. check for whitespaces as well. If the series "source" is an "object" then "0" is a string.

In this case:

```
df['source'] = df['source'].replace({'xxx': 'xxx', 'aaa': 'aaa', '0': 'test'})
```

Comment: Don't know why I did not try this before posting here.. Thank you.